# Can I use zclip in an angular method without attaching to a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'd like to have a copyText method that is agnostic as to the source of the text. The examples provided on the zclip page all make use of attaching the event to a button, but I already have a workflow for hiding/exposing information. I would like to just have the copyText method copy to clipboard at the appropriate time given the text to copy. Can I do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.zclip.js"></script>

#in angular controller:

  $scope.copyText = function(text) {
    console.log("copyText", text);
    zclip({
      path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
      copy:text
    });
  }

  $scope.method = function() {
      return $http.post('@controllerMethod()', data)
          .success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.copyText(data.result);
          });
  }
```

This currently results in zclip is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

zclip is built off of ZeroClipboard. Their documentation states that you must attach this to an element and execute after a user click for security reasons.